# How many times is $3^{20} + 3^{22}$ greater than $3^{20}$

Tags: exponentiation

I just don't know where to start any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you divide the numbers?

Comment: Is the answer nine

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Can you please tell me the answer

Comment: How did you get 9 when you divided the numbers?

Comment: Just do what the guy said, do $\frac{3^{20}+3^{22}}{3^{20}}$.

Comment: The answer is 10 OK got it

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? The user obviously has little choice when he has NO CLUE how to proceed about the question? The user would post about his attempts and where he is stuck in the details of the question ONLY IF he had found a way to proceed. What do the downvoters expect or suggest the user to do? Downvoting the downvotes....

Comment: @Deepak Gupta Thank you

Comment: @DeepakGupta The asker here has a lengthy history of posting unmotivated questions that end in phrases along the lines of "I don't know where to start." For what it's worth, I only downvoted after the comment asking for the answer, rather than engaging with (what I hoped to be) an educational line of comments.

Comment: @DeepakGupta "I don't know where to start" is NEVER an excuse. Do they know what a number is? If so, that's a start. Do they not know what a number is? Then figuring out what a number is is a start. There is ALWAYS a start, ALWAYS. This is just lazy problem (most likely homework) dumping and I don't want this kind of garbage on math.SE

Comment: Oh.. Got it.. Would be nice if down voters explained through a comment why the question is worth down voting.. It will help the user to be more responsible in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** Factor $3^{20}+3^{22}$ as $3^{20}(1+3^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

This question is tricky in the wordings.
Consider
$$\frac{3^{20}+3^{22}}{3^{20}} = \frac{3^{20}(1+3^2)}{3^{20}} = 1+3^2 = 10$$
Hence, $3^{20}+3^{22}$ is 10 times of $3^{20}$.
So, $3^{20}+3^{22}$ is $\mathbf {greater}$ than $3^{20}$ by $$10-1=9\; \text{times}$$

Comment: This is incorrect. The usual meaning of $x$ is greater than $y$ by $n$ times is $x = ny$.

Comment: Consider the equation of percentage increase: $$\frac{x-y}{y}\times 100\% =(\frac xy - 1) \times 100\% = (n-1)\times 100\% $$ Hence, $x$ is greater than $y$ by $(n-1)$ times if $x=ny$.

Comment: It's not that I don't get your point. I am telling you how the phrases "times greater than" and "times less than" are applied *in common parlance*, which is applicable to this question. In this context, your interpretation is wrong. Lay language is often imprecise.